# Bring to front a key that has a custom value - multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to find a solution for this one for the last couple of hours.

I have this multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 128
            [itemID] => 27
            [attribute] => xxx
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 129
            [itemID] => 27
            [attribute] => xxx
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 130
            [itemID] => 27
            [attribute] => xxx
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 131
            [itemID] => 27
            [attribute] => xxx
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 132
            [itemID] => 27
            [attribute] => xxx
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 133
            [itemID] => 27
            [attribute] => yyy
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 134
            [itemID] => 27
            [attribute] => xxx
        )

)
```

As you can see obj. 5 has the attribute key to 'yyy'.
I would like to bring to front this object which contains the attribute key of 'yyy' like a re-order so when i foreach, the yyy result to be first.

I have tried with different snippets found online but couldn't find one that help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your array above:

```
function sortMyArray($item1, $item2) {
    $result = 0;
    if ($item1->attribute == 'yyy') {
        $result = -1;
    }
    else if ($item2->attribute == 'yyy') {
        $result = 1;
    }
    return $result;
}

usort($yourArray, "sortMyArray");
```

Answer (score 0):

see this -  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php , may help you

so sort your array, and use custom function , that compares if attribute is what you want ( and return -1 for yyy as $a and 1 for yyy as $b , 0 otherwise )